# AWS App Sync Subscriptions are not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am using AppSync to update my DynamoDB.

I have subscribed to that particular row, updated based on the partition key but I'm not able to receive the notifications.

I was expecting the output something like below mentioned

{
  "data": {
    "Post": null
  }
}

But, I'm getting output as

```
     { "mqttConnections": 
       [ { "url": "*****",
           "topics": ["*******************************","*****************************"],
           "client": "*************" 
       } ], 
       "newSubscriptions": 
          { "UpdateDevTable": 
            { "topic": "*****************************", 
              "expireTime": 1541598037000 }  
            } 
          }
```

Can someone look into this and help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is functioning as expected. Subscriptions in AWS AppSync run on MQTT over WebSockets and the actual subscription request in GraphQL is responsible for creating an MQTT topic and configuring a credential so your client can connect to the topic. The AppSync SDKs handle connecting to the topic and streaming results into your application but you can also build your own subscription client using any MQTT client such as paho (https://www.eclipse.org/paho/).

You can learn more about how to use subscriptions from JavaScript by searching for "Make Your Application RealTime" here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-react.html

Comment: Thanks, But one more Question. So, client applications need to subscribe to the topic created by the subscription?

Comment: @BhanuPrakash Yes, the SDKs do this for you automatically but if you wanted to build your own SDK then it would need to subscribe to the MQTT topic manually.

Comment: Hi mparis, can i subscribe to a specific row on client?